# Not seeing formatting toolbar on ask question screen

Tags: discussion, bug

I was going to ask a question, and while adding my code, I noticed the following two points:

- Formatting toolbar is missing.
- Code preview section is missing.

[image]

Is that bug or a change in the UI?

Edit : I am using Chrome 75 version, also i notice, i am able to see both functionality in meta stackoverflow but not in stackoverflow.

[image]

Edit 2: Added console screenshot
[image]

Comment: any errors in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: @rene This is the error i am getting console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initEditor' of undefined"

Comment: I think that can only happen when the wmd.en.js is not loaded. What does the network tab tell you?

Comment: jQuery does get loaded, right?

Comment: @rene It only showing me validate body as success and issue in jquery.min.js

Comment: Can you [edit] which  browser you're using and if you're on some enterprise network or a consumer network., Can you repro the problem on a different network / different computer?

Comment: @rene how can i reopened this question, as SO does not letting it me pasting screenshot also?

Comment: it sits in the queue now, I guess

Comment: It would be more useful if we have screenshots of the errors as well. The console and the network tab

Comment: Just a quick check. You are on the full site view, right? Not on the mobile view [that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypcTg.jpg). At the bottom of the page there is link to switch between mobile and full site.

Comment: @rene Added  console screenshot, also ii seems to be working fine when i am connected to a VPN.

Comment: If it works fine over VPN then there is nothing SE can do. You need to talk to the network people of your provider to fix whatever they have broken.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Stack Overflow markdown editor tool bar options are not displaying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330126/289905).