# Vote Button missing (Firefox-specific)

Tags: support, firefox, browser-support

The vote buttons are and have been gone for some time.
[image: Screenshot of up-vote/down-vote, near favorite button]

Yet, I can see the same vote button on non-Firefox browsers.

Also, notable... The editor ICON button are also gone as well, but the button area are still clickable (just have to wait for the hover to pop-up a tooltip and tell you what each button area is for).
[image: Screenshot of browser-based editor menu bar for Body field]
Using Firefox Quantum 60.6.3esr (64-bit)

Addendum:  In the Firefox console, no error was reported associated with these SVG icons as having being missing.

Comment: Can you link the question on which this is happening? The post might be locked too

Comment: Post in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114179/difference-between-class-and-struct-in-with-regards-to-padding-and-inheritance

Comment: No repro FF (Quantum) v68.0.1 (64-bit), Win 10 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmltm.png

Comment: If the CDN is hosting SO icons, don’t you think that is a real issue if the CDN provider is shady?

Comment: Those images are SVG's embedded into the HTML. There is no CDN there.

Comment: Please unhold this question for my answer is specific to Firefox settings in `about:config`, specifically `svg.disabled` being set to `true`.  Problem solved.

Comment: Normally when the toolbar is missing its icons there is an error in the dev console as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386395/not-seeing-formatting-toolbar-on-ask-question-screen

Comment: It should be interesting to note that having svg.disabled does not generate a console error message, or any message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steps to enable SVG in Firefox, if disabled (it is enabled by default in the new versions of Firefox):

1. In the address bar, straight up type `about:config`. **NOTE: This can void your existing warranty, so proceed with caution.**
2. Click *I accept the risk*.
3. Type *svg* in the search bar and then you will see an entry under `svg.disabled`.
4. Now, in the "Value" column, control-click and a prompt will open (or double click it). *
5. Click modify and change the value to `false`.
6. Perform a reload (CTRL + R), or restart Firefox if the changes don't take effect.

The issue should be fixed now.

* In Firefox on Windows, double-click to toggle the value between "true" and "false".

Comment: And I turned it off while investigating a browser exploit.  So many switches, so many knobs.

Comment: I didn’t have to restart Firefox 60 for that switch.  A mere reload of the affected tab fixed it.

Comment: @JohnGreene edited my answer

Comment: [What warranty?](https://superuser.com/a/499312) ;-)